# KeyPress triggers click event when C# modal window is opened by VB6 application

Tags: c#, events, interop, modal-dialog, vb6-migration

I've created a simple C# dll which is to be called by a VB6 application. It just opens a form modally, nothing else. ShowInTaskbar is set to false.

```
namespace ComTest{
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("0A62D0AC-F396-4089-ADF0-330B356E2559")]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  public class Test
  {
    private frmTest frm = null;

    [STAThread]
    public void ShowForm()
    {
      frm = new frmTest();
      frm.ShowDialog();
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

There's one button on the form to show a "button clicked"-message box.

The VB6 application is just a form (ShowInTaskbar set to true) with a button as well. Clicking it shows the C# window. Pressing "Esc" shows a message box according to the key pressed.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim test As Object
  Set test = CreateObject("ComTest.Test")
  If Not test Is Nothing Then
    test.ShowForm
  End If
  Set test = Nothing
End Sub
```

Once the application has started (this only happens when starting the project exe, not when debugging!) and the button's been pushed in order to open the C# dialogue, I select the application's task bar icon. The VB6 window is being focused (why?) and pressing "Escape" opens up another C# dialogue (the first one's still visible though), as if the button had beed clicked again.

There's no default button on the form; when there's no open dialogue, pressing "Escape" pops up the proper message box.

This behaviour can be repeated indefinitely. I've tried setting parents and children, the common answer to such a kind of interop application is to make use of the Interop Form Toolkit.

Still I don't understand why pressing "Escape" fires the button-clicked event. Does anyone have an idea why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the VB6 app, is the buttons "Cancel" property set to True? If so it will pick up `Esc` keypresses as button clicks.